# Mercurial messes scandinavian characters OSX

Tags: windows, macos, character-encoding, mercurial

Me and my friend set up Mercurial repository on Bitbucket for our project. He works on Windows while I use OSX. I installed Mercurial to OSX and cloned the repository only to find out that all scandinavian characters (äö) in files where interpreted wrongly. Also, folders which had those characters didn't get cloned properly.

Now, I suppose it has something to do with character encoding, which makes it somehow work on Windows, but not on OSX. I used Sourcetree as GUI for Mercurial and tried to find any character encoding settings with no results. What I should do to fix this problem? I have used GUI Mercurial on Windows before and never had problems like this.

Comment: So how are they encoded in the repo, and in the file systems on the two different boxes? This is too vague to analyze without something like a hex dump of the bytes.

Comment: Looks like the files are written in ANSI on windows and OSX tries to interpret them as UTF-8.

Comment: Also chcp is 850 on my friend's Windows and everything shows correctly.

Comment: Correction, files are iso-8859-1.

Comment: Probably cp1252; Microsoft hadn't heard there was an ISO standard.

Comment: "äö in files w(h)ere interpreted wrongly" - do you mean "in filenames" (a Mercurial issue) or in file contents (a normal character encoding issue)? Please clarify.

Comment: Both file names and contents.

Answer (score 0):

You have usual "different encoding" problem.

OSX uses UTF8 (FIXME), Windows for Western-Europe 8bit chars (most probably) - ISO-8859-1

Before any CLI-operations in OSX you have to chcp to the same copepage, as it was on Win-side

Comment: Could you tell a bit more precisely what I should do? What do you mean by "chcp"? I'm relatively new osx user still so I'm not sure what I should do in it.

Comment: chcp is apparently a Windows command.  It doesn't exist on the Mac.

Comment: Better to fix the file names to UTF8 and jump through the necessary albeit no doubt mind-numbing hoops on the Windows side.

Comment: I think we have to go through that since I can't find any sensible solution to this on OSX side.